# Absolute Value of a Vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, absolute, modulus

If I have a vector: 
`A=[1,1,1]` 
I know it has length, SQRT( (1^2)+(1^2)+(1^2) ) = SQRT(3) = approx 1.73

But how do I do this in MATLAB?

I have tried:

```
abs(A)
```

But this just returns the absolute value of each element of the array. So it just returns the same array, as shown below:

```
B=abs(A) 

B=[1,1,1]
```

How do I get MATLAB to give me the absolute value of the whole vector, so I get a scalar output?

I would rather do it with a single function instead of operating on each of the elements in the vector individually, as my code is becoming quite messy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `norm` function

```
B = norm(A,2);
```

The second parameter indicates you want to use the Euclidean norm

Comment: You can omit the second parameter; it is 2 by default

Comment: @LuisMendo It is indeed but it is worth knowing in case other norms are required in future.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to use [`norm`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/norm.html):

```
norm(A)
```

You could also do it manually: raise each vector element to the power of 2, sum all results to get a single number, and compute its square root:

```
sqrt(sum(A.^2))
```